# Standard modules not found after installing on odoo 8

Tags: odoo

I'm currently trying to install a module (service level agreement module) on Odoo 8. I downloaded the zip, copied it over to the addon directory specified in the configuration file, and then restarted the server. To ensure it restarted I killed the old process, check that it was dead, and then started it up again.

I attempted to search for the module (searched for Service), and it was not found.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear after you update Module List but you need the "Technical Features" permission. You even have to set it for your admin user [like this](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-to-activate-the-technical-features-7650).

*To activate the **technical features**, you have to add access rights to your user. You must edit your current user from the menu **Settings > Users.** Edit your user (probably admin) and, in the Access Rights tab, check the option **Technical Features**.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your list of modules ? (Settings / Modules / Update Module List).

You need the 'Technical Features' rights to do that.